# Setting Absolute File-path with Wildcard to Variable in CMD .bat File

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to set a variable in a batch script to the absolute path of some file, however the filename will not be constant.

For example, the file path will be something like:

```
C:\someFolder\anotherFolder\TestFile_%.txt
```

Where `%` could be any number of characters. There will only be **one** file in this directory with the naming conventions of `TestFile_*.txt`, so I don't have to worry about multiple matches.

How can I set some variable in my script to this absolute filepath? Something like:

```
set VAR="C:\someFolder\anotherFolder\TestFile_%.txt"
echo VAR is: %VAR%
```

Where the output should be: `VAR is C:\someFolder\anotherFolder\TestFile_1234.txt`

Comment: Try this: `for %I in ("C:\someFolder\anotherFolder\TestFile_*.txt") do @echo "%~I"` (or with `%%` instead of `%` in a batch file)…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a for:

`FOR %%A in (C:\someFolder\anotherFolder\TestFile_*.txt) do (set "var=%%A")`

Searches for a files called TestFile_ with other chars and the TXT extension